# JPA and default locking mode

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

With JPA, we can use manually `OPTIMISTIC` or `PESSIMISTIC` locking to handle entity changes in transactions.

I wonder how JPA handles locking if we don't specify one of these 2 modes ?
No locking mode is used?

If we don't define an explicit locking mode, can the database integrity be lost?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've scanned through section 3.4.4 *Lock Modes* of the [Java Persistence API 2.0 Final Release](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec) specification and while I couldn't find anything *specific* (it doesn't state that *this* is the default or anything like that) there is a footnote which says the following.

> The lock mode type NONE may be specified as a value of lock mode
>   arguments and also provides a default value for annotations.

The section is about the kinds of [`LockModeType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html) values available and their usages and describes which methods takes an argument of this kind and whatnot.

So, as it said `LockModeType.NONE` is default for annotations (JPA, annotations left and right) I guess when you use `EntityManager.find(Class, Object)` the default `LockModeType` is used.

There are some other, *subtle*, hints to reinforce this. Section 3.1.1 *EntityManager interface*.

> The find method (provided it is invoked without a lock or invoked with
>   LockModeType.NONE) and the getReference method are not required to be
>   invoked within a transaction context.

It makes sense. For example if you use MySQL as your database and your database engine of choice is InnoDB then (by default) your tables will use [`REPEATABLE READ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read), if you use some other RDBMS or other database engines this could change.

Right now I'm not exactly sure that isolation levels has anything to do with JPA lock modes (although it seems that way), but my point is that different database systems differ so JPA can't decide for you (at least according to the specification) what lock mode to use by default, so it'll use `LockModeType.NONE` if you don't instruct it otherwise.

I've also found [an article regarding isolation levels and lock modes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#Isn.27t_database_transaction_isolation_all_I_need.3F), you might want to read it.

Oh, and to answer your last question.

> If we don't define an explicit locking mode, can the database
>   integrity be lost?

It *depends*, but if you have concurrent transactions then the answer is probably *yes*.

Comment: Thank you for this constructive answer and link. I will read again and try to understand LockModeType.NONE and what that implies. The fact is I'm new with JPA and I don't konw exactly what entity(ies) should I lock to keep with certitude integrity. It's probably boring but I'll test all modes with transactions simulation (Thread.sleep()). Thanks again

Answer (score 16):

Due to JPA 2.1 FR

> 3.2 Version Attributes
>
> The Version field or property is used by the persistence provider to perform optimistic locking. It is accessed and/or set by the persistence provider in the course of performing lifecycle operations on the entity instance. **An entity is automatically enabled for optimistic locking if it has a property or field mapped with a Version mapping.**

So if the entity is a versioned object, such as a @Version has been specified, then the default persistence provider will perform optimistic locking.

Answer (score 5):

In the specification persistence_2.0, page 89:

> If a versioned object is otherwise updated or removed, then the implementation must ensure that the
>   requirements of LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT are met, even if no explicit
>   call to EntityManager.lock was made.