# JPA and optimistic locking modes

Tags: jpa, transactions, locking

I read an article on the blog of Oracle [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/locking_and_concurrency_in_java) about JPA and locking modes.

I don't entirely understand the difference between `OPTIMISTIC` and `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` lock mode types.

***`OPTIMISTIC` mode :***

[image]

When a user locks an entity with this mode, a check is done on the version field entity (`@version`) at the beginning of transaction and a check on the version field is also done at the end of the transaction. If versions are different, the transaction rolls back.

***`OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` mode :***

[image]

When a user chooses this mode, he has to flush() the state of EntityManager into database to increment the version field manually. Thus, all other optimistic transactions will be invalidated (roll back). A check on the version is also done at end of transaction to commit or roll back transaction.

It seems clear but when should I use `OPTIMISTIC` versus `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` modes ? The only criteria that I see is to apply `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` mode when I want the transaction to have precedence over the others because choosing this mode will roll back all other running transactions (if I understand well mecanism).

Is there other reason to choose this mode rather than `OPTIMISTIC` mode?

Thanks

Comment: I think we use use OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT in case of updating entity which contains another type of entities as field (@oneToOne, @oneToMany). So we lock with OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT for example all ListItem when we want to update List. Thus when committing, we ensure that all entities linked with the entity that we want to update are unchanged. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally you would never use the lock() API for optimistic locking.  JPA will automatically check any version columns on any update or delete.

The only purpose of the lock() API for optimistic locking is when your update depends on another object that is not changed/updated.  This allows your transaction to still fail if the other object changes.

When to do this depends on the application and the use case.  OPTIMISTIC will ensure the other object has not been updated at the time of your commit.  OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT will ensure the other object has not been updated, and will increment its version on commit.

Optimistic locking is always verified on commit, and there is no guarantee of success until commit.  You can use flush() to force the database locks ahead of time, or trigger an earlier error.

Comment: What is the difference between NONE (default mode I think) and OPTIMISTIC so ? Thx

Comment: Is the flush() guaranteed to increment the version before the commit in a way that it is visible to other transactions?

Answer (score 57):

Don't be scared by this long answer. This topic is not simple.

By default JPA impose 
*Read committed* isolation level if you don't specify any locking (same behaviour as using `LockModeType.NONE`).

*Read committed* requires **non existence** of the *Dirty read* phenomenon. Simply T1 can only see changes made by T2 after T2 commits.

Using optimistic locking in JPA rises isolation level to 
*Repetable reads*.

If T1 reads some data at the beginning and at the end of the transaction, *Repetable reads* assures that T1 sees the same data even if T2 changed the data and committed in the middle of T1.

And here comes the tricky part. JPA achieves *Repetable reads* in the simplest way possible: by **preventing** *Non-Repetable read* phenomenon. JPA is not sophisticated enough to keep snapshots of your reads. It simply prevents second read from happening by rising an exception (if the data has changed from the first read).

You can choose from two optimistic locking options:

- `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC` (`LockModeType.READ` in JPA 1.0)
- `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` (`LockModeType.WRITE` in JPA 1.0)

**What's the difference between the two?**

Let me illustrate with examples on this `Person` entity.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id int id;
    @Version int version;
    String name;
    String label;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Car> cars;
    // getters & setters
}
```

Now let assume we have one Person named *John* stored in the database. We read this Person in T1 but change his name to *Mike* in the second transaction T2.

**Without any locking**

```
Person person1 = em1.find(Person.class, id, LockModeType.NONE); //T1 reads Person("John")

Person person2 = em2.find(Person.class, id); //T2 reads Person("John")
person2.setName("Mike"); //Changing name to "Mike" within T2
em2.getTransaction().commit(); // T2 commits

System.out.println(em1.find(Person.class, id).getName()); // prints "John" - entity is already in Persistence cache
System.out.println(
  em1.createQuery("SELECT count(p) From Person p where p.name='John'")
    .getSingleResult()); // prints 0 - ups! don't know about any John (Non-repetable read)
```

**Optimistic read lock**

```
    Person person1 = em1.find(Person.class, id, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC); //T1 reads Person("John")

    Person person2 = em2.find(Person.class, id); //T2 reads Person("John")
    person2.setName("Mike"); //Changing name to "Mike" within T2
    em2.getTransaction().commit(); // T2 commits

    System.out.println(
            em1.createQuery("SELECT count(p) From Person p where p.name='John'")
                    .getSingleResult()); // OptimisticLockException - The object [Person@2ac6f054] cannot be updated because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read.
```

---

`LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` is used when the change is made to other entity (perhaps a non-owned relationship) and we want to preserve integrity.
Let me illustrate with John acquiring a new car.

**Optimistic read lock**

```
Person john1 = em1.find(Person.class, id); //T1 reads Person("John")

Person john2 = em2.find(Person.class, id, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC); //T2 reads Person("John")
//John gets a mercedes
Car mercedes = new Car();
mercedes.setPerson(john2);
em2.persist(mercedes);
john2.getCars().add(mercedes);
em2.getTransaction().commit(); // T2 commits

//T1 doesn't know about John's new car. john1 in stale state. We'll end up with wrong info about John.
if (john1.getCars().size() > 0) { 
    john1.setLabel("John has a car");
} else {
    john1.setLabel("John doesn't have a car");
}
em1.flush();
```

**Optimistic write lock**

```
Person john1 = em1.find(Person.class, id); //T1 reads Person("John")
Person john2 = em2.find(Person.class, id, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT); //T2 reads Person("John")
//John gets a mercedes
Car mercedes = new Car();
mercedes.setPerson(john2);
em2.persist(mercedes);
john2.getCars().add(mercedes);
em2.getTransaction().commit(); // T2 commits

//T1 doesn't know about John's new car. john1 in stale state. That's ok though because proper locking won't let us save wrong information about John.
if (john1.getCars().size() > 0) { 
    john1.setLabel("John has a car");
} else {
    john1.setLabel("John doesn't have a car");
}
em1.flush(); // OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

Although there is a following remark in the JPA spec, Hibernate and EclipseLink behaves nicely and don't use it.

> For versioned objects, it is permissible for an implementation to use LockMode-
>   Type.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT where LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC was requested,
>   but not vice versa.

Comment: I think in your last example when you do em1.flush() because no lock is used, we should have not get an exception. In reality because you have used Version in your entities: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19872657/1059372

Comment: I tested my examples against Hibernate 4.3.6.Final and Eclipselink 2.5.1. About your concern: Hibernate message is visible in the comments. Eclipselink prints *OptimisticLockException The object [Person@716d7daf] cannot be updated because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read.* `Person` is indeed versioned as first snipped indicates.

Comment: I checked how it would behave without `@Vesion` column on `Person` and it would fail on locking. Hibernate with *AssertionFailure: cannot force version increment on non-versioned entity* and Eclipselink with *PersistenceException: Invalid lock mode type on for an entity that does not have a version locking index. Only a PESSIMISTIC lock mode type can be used when there is no version locking index.*

Comment: @zbig Hey, you have mentioned two examples of optimistic read lock, in first example OptimisticLockException occurs for em1 because em2 has already changed the object.
But, in second example, you have not mentioned any exception for em1 even when em2 changes object.
Please clarify..

Comment: Does "LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC" requries version column to be present in Entity?

Comment: @zbig Thank you for a very useful answer -- great examples! I asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664913/jpa-locking-when-performing-an-indirect-insertion) about indirect insertions a while back that I haven't gotten an answer for. Reading your explanations here, it seems I got it right. However, I don't call `persist` to persist the collection element entity, but rather just insert it indirectly by updating the entity that contains the collection. Is `persist` required or redundant? Would you mind having a look at my question and providing an answer, please?

Answer (score 4):

[`LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic-lock-mode-work/) suffers from `check-then-act` issues so you are better off coupling it with a [`PESSIMISTIC_READ`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-fix-optimistic-locking-race-conditions-with-pessimistic-locking/) or [`PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-fix-optimistic-locking-race-conditions-with-pessimistic-locking/).

On the other hand, [`LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`](https://vladmihalcea.com//hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/) does not suffer from any data inconsistency issue, and you'd typically use it to control the version of a parent entity whenever a child entity is modified.

For instance, you can use `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` or [`LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-pessimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/) so that the [parent entity version tales into consideration child entity changes as well](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).