# JPA/validation @ManyToOne relations should not create new rows

Tags: java, jpa

I have an JPA entity with contains a ManyToOne reference to another table, a simplified version of that entity is shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITIES")
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    @Id @NotNull
    private String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "REFERENCE", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ReferencedEntity referencedEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "REFERENCES")
public class ReferencedEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id @NotNull @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Size(max = 50) @Column(name = "DSC")
    private String description;
}
```

Finding entities works fine. Peristing entities also works fine, a bit too good in my particular setup, I need some extra validation.

**Problem**
My requirement is that the rows in table *REFERENCES* are static and should not be modified or new rows added.
Currently when I create a new *Entity* instance with a non-existing (yet) *ReferencedEntity* and persist that instance, a new row is added to *REFERENCES*.

Right now I've implemented this check in my own validate() method before calling the persist(), but I'd rather do it more elegantly.
Using an enum instead of a real entity is not an option, I want to add rows myself without a rebuild/redeployment several times in the future.

**My question**
*What is the best way to implement a check like this?

Is there some BV annotation/constraint that helps me restrict this? Maybe a third party library?*

Comment: u can mark entity `@immuteable` if you do not want overwrite every time and rest depends on your `persistence.xml` how you have declared

Comment: If he was using Hibernate.

Comment: No, I am not using Hibernate. I'm using EclipseLink as JPA implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to first do a DB query to check if the value exists and then insert the record. This must be done in a transaction in order to ensure that the result of the query is still true at the time of insertion. I had a similar problem half a year back which might provide you with some leads on how to set up locking. [Please see this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664913/jpa-locking-when-performing-an-indirect-insertion)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only solution for me. I'm wondering if I can put this in a custom validator though..

Answer (score 0):

You should add this => insertable=false, updatable=false

And remove => optional=false , and maybe try nullable=true