# Hibernate/JPA: Update then delete in one transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to execute an update query then a delete query right after the update one in the same transaction? I'm trying to activate an account based on a token's hash and then remove that token in the same transaction.

```
transaction.begin();
entityManager
.createNativeQuery(
                      "UPDATE accounts AS ac "
                    + "INNER JOIN account_tokens AS ak ON ac.id = ak.account_id "
                    + "SET ac.account_state = "
                    + "CASE "
                    + "WHEN ac.account_state = 'AWAITING_ACTIVATION' THEN 'ACTIVATED' "
                    + "END "
                    + "WHERE ak.token_hash = :tokenHash")
                    .setParameter()
                    .executeUpdate();
em.createNativeQuery(
                      "DELETE FROM account_tokens AS ak "
                    + "WHERE ak.token_hash = :tokenHash")
                    .setParameter()
                    .executeUpdate(); // delete
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: logically possible. you are updating and deleting on different tables that's fine. doing on same table may lead data inconsistency.

Comment: Its logically quite okay. I dont find any problem with that. Whats you specific confusion ? Did you get any problem with any scenarion ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud thing is that I'm deleting the first entity after executing the update query - I'm using an inner join and update a table on Its foreign key and after that, I'd like to remove the entity. Maybe I should have mentioned this in the question, my bad. Would this be alright?-- I won't have any data inconsistency since this is one-time thing

Comment: You can update your question anytime. Could you please mention the the *update* and *delete* query that your are handling? You have described that, I know. But seeing the queries would clear the picture more concisely. Please update your question with these details.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud Done. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, +1. You may also want to consider if there's a need for locking. I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38664913/1214974) last year that might be relevant in that case.

Comment: @VioAriton How about calling `em.flush()` right after first update query?  I sense it will force update query execution before delete. And thus you could avoid uncertainity of query execution order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Use PL/SQL Procedure.

You can't reduce the number of queries - they all do different things - but you could reduce the number of round trips to the database and the number of parses by wrapping it all as a PLSQL function.

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE s_u_d(a)
    BEGIN

    UPDATE tab_x SET tab_x.avalue=1 WHERE tab_x.another=a;

    DELETE FROM tab_y WHERE tab_y.avalue=a;

    SELECT * 
    FROM tab_x
    WHERE tab_x.another=a;

    END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, unfortunately, I use MySQL.