# JPA optimistic locking and write grants only to version field

Tags: java, database, jpa, entity, eclipselink

- I have read grants on a table from another schema,
- I also have write grants on the version column of this table.

Now my question is:
I want to map this table to a JPA Entity,
given this configuration
Would JPA be ok when using optimistic locking (`LockModeType.OPTIMICTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`),
I mean would JPA
have any truble with having write grants only to the version column ?

Comment: but if you cannot update any other columns on that table, then why you would need to update version column on itself anyway?

Comment: You would still have the need to do so, to make sure the entity does not change until commit time. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581603/jpa-and-optimistic-locking-modes