# JPA optimistic lock with SQLServer TIMESTAMP

Tags: jpa, timestamp, locking, optimistic

I am trying to setup JPA optimistic lock on SQLServer. For that purpose I use a `TIMESTAMP` column (SQLServer `TIMESTAMP` is an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time).

Being an auto-incrementing number, on my Java entity I need to set insertable/updatable to `false` otherwise I would get an exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot update a timestamp column

Here is my Java entity mapping:

```
@Version
@Column(name = "TSROWVERSION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private byte[] version;
```

When I update a record this SQL is executed:

```
(1) *SELECT ... FROM cmd_e_entities WHERE uidentity=?*

(2) *UPDATE cmd_e_entities SET... WHERE uidentity=?*
```

but I was expecting to get something like:

```
(3) *UPDATE cmd_e_entities SET... WHERE uidentity=? AND tsrowversion=?*
```

Hibernate executes first a `SELECT` to check if the record has changed (1), and then it updates (2). If the record was changed it throws an exception:

> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

So it works fine, but I was expecting the `UPDATE` to take into account the version (3). Actually if a change the sql type from `TIMESTAMP` to `NUMBER` and remove insertable/updateble it works as expected.

If the `UPDATE` does not consider the version (`... AND tsrowversion=?`) how can optimistic lock be guaranteed? How can I get my expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate checks that the version of the in memory entity is the same as the persisted one. Entity's id doesn't change, besides Hibernate keep only one version of an entity so there is no need to "filter" on version column.
Maybe this [JPA and optimistic locking modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581603/jpa-and-optimistic-locking-modes?rq=1) could help