# JPA: LockModeType.NONE

Tags: jpa, transactions, locking, isolation-level

Am I right with  following ?

JPA: LockModeType.**NONE** means:

There is **no explicit locking on JPA level** / application layer

In the absence of explicit locking on JPA level, the application will use **implicit** locking

Implicit locking means, **JPA is delegating the whole locking responsibility to the database system**

If the database system has as default islation level, for example Committed Read, so JPA-LockModeType.NONE will cause that transactions will be handled as Committed Read

So, JPA-LockModeType.NONE is not the same as Uncommited Read because no database system has Uncommited Read as default, and it's also a little misleading because a database system always uses locks even with Uncommited Read.

is this correct ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA and default locking mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568475/jpa-and-default-locking-mode)

Comment: Different database vendors implements isolation levels on your own. For example Oracle has only three isolation levels: Read Committed, Serializable and Read-Only. So if you use LockModeType.NONE it means the Read Commited isolation level, becouse Oracle does not support "NONE" isolation type.