# Optimistic and Pessimistic locking at the same time

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I have a basic understanding of transactions, isolation, propagation and locking. I have a Spring Boot application that is backed by a SQL server database.

There is a REST endpoint that calls a `@Transactional` service method to create a new `Order` and simulaneously updates a related `User` entity.

The traffic to the application is high and I get very often Exceptions for different transactions that are related to **both**, optimistic and pessimistic locking:

- `org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException` which is a `PessimisticLockingFailureException`
- `org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`

Both exceptions can occur on the same service method call when a concurrent transaction tries to update the same `User`.

As there is nothing configured, [default locking mode should be optimistic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568475/jpa-and-default-locking-mode). I have a `@Version` annotated field on both `Order` and `User` which indicates that opimistic locking should be used. On the Spring Repositories there are no `@Lock` annotations.

**How is it possible that a `PessimisticLockingFailureException` can occur?**

Comment: Are you sure it is a Pessimistic locking situation? If you lookup other questions involving the CannotAcquireLockException, they seem to be due to database deadlocks, and spring might just have mis-mapped the cause. One process inserts/updates/Deletes might cause a table lock somewhere else (on other tables) if you don't have foreign keys indexed, allowing deadlocks in your statements to occur. Or you could be inadvertently using pessimistic locking in a query (select for update) somewhere as well. You'll have to look at the statements issued in the two transactions involved.

Comment: You could be right about the miss-mapping. I'm made a test with parallel calls with a H2 and MSSQL database. On the H2 I'm getting only `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` while on MSSQL I primarily get `CannotAcquireLockException` and sometimes `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` for the same test.